# Set CSS Left property of UL using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

So i'm trying to make my schools navigation bar a little bit more mobile friendly.
If you navigate to 
www.jpc.wa.edu.au
on a mobile device, and click on the menu item "Resources" - A drop down menu opens up with two options. Mousing over these with a desktop computer gives you another menu to the right of the first. This works fine on a large screen. However, anything that has a resolution lower than roughly 1460px, such as most tablets, phones, or even laptops, the new menu gets cut off and you have to pan the window left to view it. I would like to avoid this problem completely by simply positioning the second submenu to the left of the first submenu on smaller screens.
Determining screen size I can do.

```
if(window.innerWidth<1460)
```

Works perfectly fine. The problem i'm having is that I can't seem to access the second submenus left property to modify the menus position from my javascript

In my CSS, I set it by using the following selector

```
#horizonMenu
```

But when I try to use this selector in Javascript using

```
document.querySelector("#horizonMenu").style.left
```

But that doesn't seem to return any values.

What am I doing wrong guys? Or should I just take a whole different strategy to fixing this problem?

Edit: I've now changed horizonMenu to a class. Alas, my problem seems to persist :(

Comment: I think it look nicer to simply put the submenu options below the main options, instead of to the right/left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. so it may have been a combination of a few things.

1. I followed JBzd's advice to change the menu to a class.
2. I also stopped using querySelector() and instead am using querySelectorAll() - storing what's returned as a variable and accessing the correct menus by using varaible[1] and variable[2]
3. I am now able to access the left property of the menu by using

   ```
   variable[x].style.left = '162px'
   ```

Thanks for all the help everyone :)

Comment: I also don't have enough reputation to set this as the answer, nor hand out any upvotes to the people who've helped me. Sorry guys :(

Answer (score 1):

`style` property is the representation of the `style` attribute. Since you are setting the CSS property in your `CSS` file, the `left` property returns an empty string. Also properties of the `style` object do not show the *computed* values. For getting the computed value you should use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) function.

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("#horizonMenu"), null)
      .getPropertyValue('left')
```

For setting the property value you can code:

```
document.querySelector("#horizonMenu").style.left = '...';
```

Note that you can consider using CSS media queries instead of using JavaScript.

Comment: This seems to work for returning the left value. But is there like a setProperty function that I can use to modify it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have multiple elements with the ID horizonMenu. You should only have a single element with a given ID. When you query #horizonMenu, it is returning the Community -> Pastoral Care menu, which does not have a left value. You should use classes instead, as you can have multiple elements share a class, or change the id to something unique so you can access what you intend to access.

Comment: I've changed horizonMenu to a class, but i still seem unable to access it's left property :(

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following links

[Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascripts) and http://www.kirupa.com/html5/setting_css_styles_using_javascript.htm

Also please check the position attribute for the elements, see below example:
https://jsfiddle.net/masoodalam78/e3erq6j4/

```
var elementObj = document.querySelector("#menu");
elementObj.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
elementObj.left = "200px";
```

Comment: These are the strategies that i've been trying to employ. Unfortunately, they too seem unable to access the property that I need.
The var elementObj = document.querySelector(".horizonMenu").left - Should return the left property of the horizontal menu (now a class) - But instead it returns "undefined"