# Set HTML style position in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a for loop, and I want that in my line, the left property of style, depends on my variable:

```
var pos = (i*100+100)px;

document.getElementsByName("ok")[i].style = 'position:absolute; left:pos';
```

Something like that.

Comment: i think you are looking for a javascript answer, so your html tag is wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set CSS Left property of UL using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664572/set-css-left-property-of-ul-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can something like this

```
var pos = (i*100+100);

const elem = document.getElementsByName("ok")[i];

elem.style.position = 'absolute';
elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
```

Comment: A useful list of properties of the style object can be found here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like

```
var DOM_elements = document.getElementsByName("ok");

for(var i=0; i < DOM_tags.length; i++) {
    var element = DOM_elements[i];
    var pos = (i*100+100);

    element.setAttribute('style','position:absolute; left:' + pos.toString());
}
```

This is risky though. You are in effect overwriting all other attributes of style (is that what you want?). Also worth noting - `element.style` is an object (not a string), so perhaps you would like `element.style.position = 'absolute';` or something like that.